# Execute a test inside a callback

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, systemjs

Is possible to execute a test that lies within a callback? For example I have

```
System.import("mymodule").then(function(Mymodule) {
  describe("Mymodule", function() {
    it("does something", function() {
      expect(Mymodule.dosomething()).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

This test never run. Same goes with a simple `setTimeout`

```
var Mymodule = { dosomething: function(){ return true; } };

setTimeout(function() {
  describe("Mymodule", function() {
    it("does something", function() {
      expect(Mymodule.dosomething()).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Are there any way to do this? Otherwise I have a lot of problems including modules in async fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. I include this file **as last one**:

```
basePath = "/base/spec/"

modules = []

for own fileName, fileHash of window.__karma__.files
  if fileName.indexOf(basePath) is 0
    isRunner   = fileName.indexOf("spec_runner") >= 0
    isRunner ||= fileName.indexOf("spec_helper") >= 0
    unless isRunner
      moduleName = fileName.replace(basePath, "")
      moduleName = moduleName.replace(".js", "")
      modules.push(path: fileName, name: moduleName)

mappedModules = {}
baseSpecsPath = "http://localhost:9876"
specModules   = []

for module in modules
  mappedModules[module.name] = baseSpecsPath + module.path
  specModules.push(module.name)

System.config
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4567/javascripts/"
  map:     mappedModules

moduleImports = specModules.map (moduleName) ->
  System.import(moduleName)

Promise.all(moduleImports).then ->
  window.__karma__.start     = window.__lastKarmaStart__
  window.__lastKarmaStart__  = null
  delete window.__lastKarmaStart__
  window.__karma__.start()
```

It does the following things:

- Temporary disable karma start function replacing it with a null one
- Fetches each test stored in a `System.register`, run `System.import` for all tests
- After all imports are completed, it attaches back `__karma__start` and executes it, running Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

From: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

You should describe test in synchronous manner, accept `done` callback in you `it` function, perform some async operations and call the callback after you done.

Example from jasmine site

```
  describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    var originalTimeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });

    it("takes a long time", function(done) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        done();
      }, 9000);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Uhm, this is to handle async in tests, but in this case I need to import the module to even write the test. It's not a bad approach, but I wished for a more generic one, because all my tests require `System.import` to even run